# Android: Twitter and OAuth anyone?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I was wondering if anyone got this working. I am trying to do a basic authentication but for some reason it keeps complaining "Could not authenticate you.". How would I go about getting it to run with OAUTH?

Answer (score 4):

[I have a tutorial](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/) written for this a while back. You can get it on my blog here, it's lengthy so I won't repost it here

Comment: I am very new to the OAuth concepts. I am trying to read but I don't understand what OAUTH_VERIFIER is and where to define that. Could you provide me a bit of help on that?

Comment: Also, it keeps giving me "oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException: Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy." no matter how I try to do it... I checked your blogpost but I still seem to be doing something wrong. Any suggestions on that regard?

Comment: OAUTH_VERIFIER is nothing more than a static String
`public static final String OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier"`

The way Twitter's OAuth works (in the nutshell) - when you register your app w/Twitter you are given a request token. With that token your user can go to the Twitter site and exchange his credentials + request token for the authentication token which your Android app will save and use on user's behalf to grant user access to Twitter API.

Comment: BTW - app you register on Twitter and your own Android app are not the same it's 2 totally different things

Answer (score 1):

The signpost solution is a lot of extra work.

There's a way to do it wither Twitter4j that only takes a few lines of code. The solution comes from Stephan, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528471/695787).

I have an example app using his approach, [here](https://github.com/jamesonwilliams/AndroidTwitterExample/blob/master/src/org/nosemaj/twitterexample/TwitterActivity.java).