# Twitter Application-android

Tags: android, twitter4j

I am new to twitter .I like to develope one twitter Application. Can anyone tell me:

1. The methods to be used for replying the tweets.
2. How to retweet with userID in arraylist

Answer (score 0):

you can use `OAuth` for your twitter application. You can refer to these links to learn how to make calls using the same

[Android: Twitter and OAuth anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634700/android-twitter-and-oauth-anyone)

http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/40511/0/page/1

http://blog.sogeti.com/mobile/2010/03/twitter-oauth-for-android.html

http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/#awp::2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/

Comment: Hi,whether it is possible to retweet from my own application on twitter4j libraries