# Where I can get the application source code?

Tags: android, open-source

Where can I get Android application source?
I want to find a sample application project source code that I can use for teaching and present a sample android project. The application I want is the application that get the feed from twitter, facebook
Thank you

Comment: What android application's source do you want?

Comment: Have you downloaded the SDK? Each SDK has a good number of sample projects to demonstrate API features and capabilities. If those does not server your purpose, what kind of sample do you need?

Comment: I want the application that get the feed information like twitter.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a dozen of Android application source samples at the android developer resource.

Sample apps : Accelerometer Play,Bluetooth Chat,Note Pad,Snake and more.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html

Even more samples here:

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/

**[Updated]**

As asked in the coments by the poster, I recommend:

Twitter4j for twitter:
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Facebook-java-api for facebook:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 3):

Start here for the samples!

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

A more complete appliation with source and a tutorial is found here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

As your comment asks: Some help on twitter-on android can be found in this stackoverflow thread: [Twitter Application-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626013/twitter-application-android)

Answer (score 0):

The source code for all sample applications is located on your system, in the android sdk installed on your system, Please go to the directory where you install the android SDK, find samples folder, and then get the source code of all sample applicatoin.

Regards