# Need help with tweeting from android application

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing an android application in which a tweet option is to be implemented. I have downloaded the jTwitter.jar file and when i try to tweet from my application it says the login is invalid, eventhoigh i can login to twitter from a pc using the same login details.Please help.

Comment: Twitter API calls must authenticate through OAuth. Have you implemented that?

Comment: Well, using third party libraries can be a bit tricky ... but you will have to post some additional data so we cant try to help you

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, Yock-> I havent implemented OAuth Lamberga , what additional data do u except, do u want me to post the code

Comment: Can you help me with implementation of OAuth

Comment: might help http://blog.sogeti.com/mobile/2010/03/twitter-oauth-for-android.html    and this too (from here) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634700/android-twitter-and-oauth-anyone